# Good and thorough online and/or free Matroid Theory references?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, graph-theory, matroids

I'm studying a course on Matroid theory. Sadly, I can't really afford buying the textbook, so I only use the lecture notes, which aren't enough for me.

Are there any good and thorough online and or/free references on Matroid theory?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: I'm not aware of a good, free matroid theory reference. My best advice would be to see what your university library has, and if you don't have success there, you can get a used paperback copy of the 2006 version of Oxley's book for about \$16, or a used paperback copy of Welsh's book for about \$11 both on Amazon.